# How to get Angular ui-router to route on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I am trying to set up angular routing. When I navigate to a route using `<a ui-sref="classification.sequences.index">` it gets routed to the correct location,changes the url to `http://localhost/classification/sequences/index` and outputs enter 0, enter 5, enter 2 in the console.

But if I manually refresh the page or navigate to this url from scratch no routing happens and nothing is outputted to the console. But if I click the link button it will then route properly.

Is there something you have to set so angular will attempt to route on load or have I made a silly mistake somewhere?

My code can be seen below-

```
policyManagerApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        // Activates HTML5 History API for modern browsers and sets the hashbang
        // for legacy browsers
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

        $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/classification/index");
        $urlRouterProvider.when("/", "/classification/index");

        // For any unmatched url, send to /classification/index
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/classification/index");

        $stateProvider
            .state('classification', {
                url: '/classification',
                abstract: true,
                template: '<ui-view/>',
                onEnter: function () {
                    console.log("enter 0");
                }
            })
            .state('classification.index', {
                url: '/index',
                templateUrl: '/html/partials/classification/index.html',
                controller: 'PolicyManagerCtrl',
                data: {
                    ncyBreadcrumbLabel: 'Classification'
                },
                onEnter: function () {
                    console.log("enter 1");
                }
            })
            .state('classification.sequences', {
                url: '/sequences',
                abstract: true,
                template: '<ui-view/>',
                onEnter: function () {
                    console.log("enter 5");
                }
            })
            .state('classification.sequences.index', {
                url: '/index',
                templateUrl: '/html/partials/classification/sequences/index.html',
                data: {
                    ncyBreadcrumbLabel: 'Collection Sequences'
                },
                onEnter: function () {
                    console.log("enter 2");
                }
            })
            .state('classification.sequences.detail', {
                url: '/:id',
                templateUrl: '/html/partials/classification/sequences/detail.html',
                controller: 'SequenceDetailCtrl',
                data: {
                    ncyBreadcrumbParent: 'classification.sequences.index',
                    ncyBreadcrumbLabel: '{{sequence.name}}'
                },
                onEnter: function () {
                    console.log("enter 3");
                }
            })
        ;
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I wasn't calling `policyManagerApp.run()` after the config line so it was never evaluating against the starting url.